# unable to add regression line equation on time series: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a time series using ggplot2.

```
 p1<-ggplot(df1,aes(x=Date,y=Value))+
  geom_line(color = "#0099f9",size=0.7)+
  geom_point(color = "#0099f9",size=2.5)+
  xlab('YEAR') +
  ylab('Value')+
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0.01, 0))+
  stat_smooth(color = "#FC4E07" ,se=F,method = "loess", linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5,face="bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1))
```

this runs normally and produces a graph. however when I use the following lines to add the equation on the plot I get the error: Error: `Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

```
fit1 <- lm(Value ~ Date, data = df1)
eqn1 <- sprintf("y = %.2 f + %.2f x", coef(fit1)[1], coef(fit1)[2])

p1<-p1+geom_text(aes(x = -Inf, y = Inf,label = eqn1),vjust = 1.5, hjust = -0.1, size = 7, color = "#FC4E07")
```

I'm confused on where the problem is. here are the details of the data frame.

```
str(df1)
'data.frame':   200 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date : Date, format: "1979-01-01" "1979-02-01" "1979-03-01" "1979-04-01" ...
 $ Value: num  0.0396 0.7923 0.2091 0.5291 0.6034 ...
```

the date value is in date class so error shouldn't come.

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3287, 3318, 3346, 3377, 3407, 
3438, 3468, 3499, 3530, 3560, 3591, 3621, 3652, 3683, 3712, 3743, 
3773, 3804, 3834, 3865, 3896, 3926, 3957, 3987, 4018, 4049, 4077, 
4108, 4138, 4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 4291, 4322, 4352, 4383, 4414, 
4442, 4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 4595, 4626, 4656, 4687, 4717, 4748, 
4779, 4807, 4838, 4868, 4899, 4929, 4960, 4991, 5021, 5052, 5082, 
5113, 5144, 5173, 5204, 5234, 5265, 5295, 5326, 5357, 5387, 5418, 
5448, 5479, 5510, 5538, 5569, 5599, 5630, 5660, 5691, 5722, 5752, 
5783, 5813, 5844, 5875, 5903, 5934, 5964, 5995, 6025, 6056, 6087, 
6117, 6148, 6178, 6209, 6240, 6268, 6299, 6329, 6360, 6390, 6421, 
6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 6605, 6634, 6665, 6695, 6726, 6756, 
6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 6909, 6940, 6971, 6999, 7030, 7060, 7091, 
7121, 7152, 7183, 7213, 7244, 7274, 7305, 7336, 7364, 7395, 7425, 
7456, 7486, 7517, 7548, 7578, 7609, 7639, 7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 
7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 7943, 7974, 8004, 8035, 8066, 8095, 
8126, 8156, 8187, 8217, 8248, 8279, 8309, 8340, 8370, 8401, 8432, 
8460, 8491, 8521, 8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 8705, 8735, 8766, 
8797, 8825, 8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 9009, 9039, 9070, 9100, 
9131, 9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 9312, 9343), class = "Date"), 
    Value = c(0.0396257280372083, 0.792254076339304, 0.209117455175146, 
    0.529065352398902, 0.603375660488382, 0.319143296219409, 
    0.395686875795946, 0.907367086969316, 0.214899873128161, 
    0.845133831258863, 0.729593698866665, 0.23446642444469, 0.695456632180139, 
    0.609369153855368, 0.804903780575842, 0.717942415038124, 
    0.708948610117659, 0.586231412598863, 0.428744627162814, 
    0.289207409368828, 0.261673229746521, 0.0517897910904139, 
    0.399881781078875, 0.491419325815514, 0.660340357106179, 
    0.397569235647097, 0.719583918107674, 0.0527276170905679, 
    0.299225802300498, 0.600920942146331, 0.692732113646343, 
    0.359461600426584, 0.41012356011197, 0.654954002005979, 0.00501723401248455, 
    0.95377110154368, 0.745722888037562, 0.781670887488872, 0.297899815021083, 
    0.544447399210185, 0.270234991330653, 0.744834579760209, 
    0.457057158928365, 0.319076047977433, 0.467465160181746, 
    0.873203304363415, 0.00973224942572415, 0.525288483127952, 
    0.987205622019246, 0.821595306508243, 0.444444488268346, 
    0.423219494288787, 0.957183523569256, 0.700562145095319, 
    0.0627007535658777, 0.85160772013478, 0.112801872659475, 
    0.860109773464501, 0.839778766036034, 0.0800019965972751, 
    0.570089245447889, 0.138796605635434, 0.0599930980242789, 
    0.850726855220273, 0.187702437164262, 0.477955089416355, 
    0.44590290565975, 0.591855063103139, 0.220722594996914, 0.137945054331794, 
    0.276140772737563, 0.555247570155188, 0.583037694916129, 
    0.414306864375249, 0.259164260001853, 0.704047953011468, 
    0.820138399256393, 0.187290345318615, 0.021821113768965, 
    0.480921486392617, 0.335172405699268, 0.65701438812539, 0.719875351525843, 
    0.826985993655398, 0.188403950538486, 0.979418985778466, 
    0.880327768158168, 0.459435713244602, 0.899967525154352, 
    0.63023396464996, 0.429708898067474, 0.419689932372421, 0.679789466783404, 
    0.935549516929314, 0.15216495259665, 0.58040455612354, 0.588773664552718, 
    0.302787747932598, 0.477910435758531, 0.790613159071654, 
    0.298687025438994, 0.351667754119262, 0.993604320334271, 
    0.647046210477129, 0.284127758815885, 0.70262410887517, 0.0148184688296169, 
    0.0293688937090337, 0.681327062658966, 0.401758651249111, 
    0.417004751972854, 0.49612541985698, 0.441743229515851, 0.724668584531173, 
    0.82554557477124, 0.66471484862268, 0.707551871426404, 0.924636604497209, 
    0.891580238705501, 0.575800632592291, 0.48037875094451, 0.537902092793956, 
    0.639664534013718, 0.338856110116467, 0.889717331621796, 
    0.7493839727249, 0.313021246809512, 0.593599291983992, 0.152630586409941, 
    0.0162873985245824, 0.443004894768819, 0.137859313283116, 
    0.770382518880069, 0.825071637053043, 0.547108234604821, 
    0.762059377972037, 0.184374007163569, 0.0704278845805675, 
    0.975533499382436, 0.935448106378317, 0.0500200022943318, 
    0.190880338894203, 0.279884484829381, 0.380133863538504, 
    0.660563811194152, 0.984935140237212, 0.204079145332798, 
    0.692034333012998, 0.477057519135997, 0.398255903739482, 
    0.391803733538836, 0.825130457058549, 0.455573290586472, 
    0.0229971604421735, 0.0992102834861726, 0.540488281752914, 
    0.487516192952171, 0.574387381318957, 0.620537696639076, 
    0.384882270591334, 0.657185624819249, 0.747470932547003, 
    0.538966090651229, 0.884251141222194, 0.398574377875775, 
    0.75206046900712, 0.544822150375694, 0.448297741822898, 0.369472151389346, 
    0.332336842315271, 0.145391083555296, 0.876680750632659, 
    0.963439451064914, 0.157352658221498, 0.799375151982531, 
    0.442906379466876, 0.591339654987678, 0.00191973126493394, 
    0.340572453802451, 0.466652521165088, 0.383389285299927, 
    0.627100618788972, 0.0985251953825355, 0.452199894469231, 
    0.22930586966686, 0.620492672314867, 0.23723890632391, 0.849632628029212, 
    0.587177567649633, 0.0356330594513565, 0.530038081342354, 
    0.782372932881117, 0.931947859935462, 0.706536986399442, 
    0.778071614913642, 0.486462311586365, 0.901525277877226, 
    0.98282943549566, 0.913252690341324, 0.280951054533944)), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first, unrelated issue is that you use aes inside `geom_text(`) which, even if it would work, would plot the formula to every data point, which you probably not intend to do. So I am going to remove it and use `annotate()` instead.

The second issue is related to `x` within `the geom_text()`. Since your axis is of date format, x has to be supplied as a date as well.

So if you do (EDIT: as @stefan correctly pointed out, `annotate()` is better to use)

```
p1<-ggplot(df1,aes(x=Date,y=Value))+
  geom_line(color = "#0099f9",size=0.7)+
  geom_point(color = "#0099f9",size=2.5)+
  xlab('YEAR') +
  ylab('Value')+
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0.01, 0))+
  stat_smooth(color = "#FC4E07" ,se=F,method = "loess", linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5,face="bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1))

fit1 <- lm(Value ~ Date, data = df1)
eqn1 <- sprintf("y = %.2 f + %.2f x", coef(fit1)[1], coef(fit1)[2])

p1<-p1 + annotate("text", as.Date("1985-01-01"), y=0.5, label = eqn1)
```

you would get:
[image]

Is this close to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Note that you are still adding a label for each observation. But now they are placed on top of each other at same x and y position. That's why the label looks as is if you used a "bold" fontface. A better approach would be to use `annotate`.

Comment: You are absolutely right @stefan. I have edited my answer to reflect your point.

Comment: That is easily overlooked. Had a hard time myself to learn about that. One more point. When you set the x position for the label you could do `x = as.Date("1985-01-01")`.

Comment: And once again you are right. I have edited my answer again. This probably happened because where I come from we write dates usually in another format :)

Comment: @stefan could you elaborate on why annotate is better to use than geom_text. I'm not understanding 'adding a label for each observation.'

Comment: If you run `p1+geom_text(aes(label = eqn1),vjust = 1.5, hjust = -0.1, size = 7, color = "#FC4E07")` instead of the annotation() example you might see what we were talking about. Using `geom_text()` will add the label (the formula) to every datapoint. Since I was originally specifying one location, they still got all plotted, just above each other, which is not a nice way of doing things.